# How to prevent that the Flutter AppBar menu icon overlaps a slider in the AppBar?

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with the width of the slider because the menu overlaps the slider a bit. How can I program an automatic width of the slider to prevent overlapping?

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    titleSpacing: 0,
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.brush)),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.undo)),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.redo)),
        Slider(value: x, min: 0, max: 100, divisions: 100),
      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      PopupMenuButton<String>(
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap Slider with Expanded widget

```
Expanded(child: Slider(value: x, min: 0, max: 100, divisions: 100),),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a SizedBox(width: 10) between widgets

Answer (score 0):

use Device Width

```
var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```